# Whats the difference between the following conditions in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, conditional-statements, truthiness

```
if (!value || value.length<1) 
if (value.length<1)
```

What's the difference between the two conditions? Wouldn't it be same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `value` is `null` or `undefined`, the second `if` will throw an error stating that you can't access `length` of `null` / `undefined`.

The first one prevents that, as it will only be accessing `value.length` if `value` is truthy. Otherwise, the first condition (`!value`) is satisfied, so the second one (`value.length < 1`) won't even be evaluated.

```js
const arr1 = null;
const arr2 = [];

// Satisfies first condition:
if (!arr1 || arr1.length < 1) console.log('No values in arr1.');

// Satisfies second condition:
if (!arr2 || arr2.length < 1) console.log('No values in arr2.');

// Breaks:
if (arr1.length < 1) console.log('No values in arr1.');
```

Anyway, that's not specific to TS, it's just how vanilla JS works.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are absolutely different.

```
!value
```

this checks for whether an item is present and it is not undefined, but `![] and also ![3]` this is always false. basically it checks for presence.

and even `[]` is always true.

```
length
```

calculates the no of elements inside that array and it is purely applied to array.

for `[] , value.length<1 this returns true.`

Answer (score 0):

Quick way to understand is you cannot access `length` property of an undefined array. So the second `if` condition will throw an error akin to `Cannot access property 'length' of undefined`.

The first `if` condition however checks if the array is defined. So it won't throw any error.

Typescript contains a native way of doing this check using a "safe navigation operator" or [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) `?.`. So in TS, you could simply do

```js
if (value?.length < 1) { }
```

It is equivalent to JS

```js
if ((value === null || value === void 0 ? void 0 : value.length) < 1) { }
```